# call previously defined function in wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, nested

I defined a working function called "firstname" that performs properly.  In my second function, I want to reference it.  What am I doing wrong?  I know the PHP call I am using doesn't work, but hopefully you understand what my goal is.  This is all in my functions.php file of course.

```
// Define function to get form field values:

// Working:

function firstname(){
$firstname = $_GET["Field1"];
echo $firstname;
}

// Find and replace values:

function replace_text_wps($text) {
    $text = str_replace('firstname', '<?php firstname(); ?>', $text);
    $text = str_replace('tech support', '<a href="/techsupport">Tech support</a>',         $text);
    $text = str_replace('computers', '<a href="/computers">Computers</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');
```

Comment: I don't think you want to echo `$firstname` back. I think you want to `return $firstname;`.

Comment: thank you!  that fixed the rendering issue I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, you could go with

```
$text = str_replace('firstname', firstname(), $text);
```

Wordpress won't re-parse any PHP in the text after it has gone through a filter.

Also, as mrtsherman commented, you want `return $firstname` in the `firstname()` function.

Comment: Ok I managed to figure it out and noting that I should return the value helped me figure out the last part as it wasn't rendering right using echo.  Thank you !!

Comment: `$text = str_replace('firstname', $firstname, $text);` thanks @mrtsherman and @Juhana

Comment: @gabearnold - be sure to mark Juhana's answer as the correct one! Glad it is working for you now.